# Cookies and Sessions become "null" after redirecting to another page in Asp.net

Tags: session, redirect, cookies, null

I am setting one Session and one cookie after user login, in checking some condition, user is redirected to another page, but exactly after page_load event, the Session and Cookie set to NULL. 
whats the problem of that?

this is my code:

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LastSession"] != null)
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("LastSession");
       HttpCookie cookieLogSession = new HttpCookie("LastSession", strLogInID);
       cookieLogSession.Expires = dtNow.AddDays(7);
       //cookieLogSession.Path = "/";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieLogSession);
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Ad_LastSession"] != null)
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("Ad_LastSession");

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Ad_LastSession");
    cookie.Value = (a variable);
    //cookie.Path = "/";
    cookie.Expires = dtNow.AddDays(7);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: The other page - is that in the same domain?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen yes. Domains are the same. Is it possible to have any specific Setting in Windows , or webconfig? bytheway. enableSessionState="true" in web.config